# csvcut ignores -e command line option thru pipe

Tags: pipe, csvkit

EDIT: problem/issue/solution is explained here:
https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/issues/898
A fix involves setting the environment variable PYTHONIOENCODING

---

Today I learned I need to use the -e ENCODING option to deal my input data (it's ascii with some characters > 0x7f. "extended ascii") to csvcut, so for example

```
csvcut -v -e latin-1 -c AGE,NAME input.txt
```

works as expected, however

```
cat input.txt | csvcut -v -e latin-1 -c AGE,NAME
```

does not, failing with an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 22: invalid continuation byte
```

In other words, csvcut appears to be ignoring the -e option in the 2nd case.

the file input.txt is

```
NAME,AGE
Jimmie, 10
Ñandor, 357
```

Ñ is hex 0xd1

Why would the results be different thru the pipe? Is there a fix?

Comment: At the start of the question you state _"The workaround involves setting the environment variable PYTHONIOENCODING"_, but isn't that actually the _solution_ rather than just a _workaround_? Or does setting PYTHONIOENCODING simply not work when you pipe the input?

Comment: ya, maybe a bad choice of words on my part.

Comment: OK, but to be clear: [1] Does setting PYTHONIOENCODING resolve the issue, or does its value get ignored? [2] If it does resolve the issue, is the point of your question simply to find a solution that does not involve setting PYTHONIOENCODING?

Comment: [1] yes, as near as i can tell, it does solve the problem, and [2] well, I originally asked the question without any understanding that PYTHONIOENCODING was a thing or even that csvkit uses Python.
To my way of thinking, the end-user (me in this case) shouldn't need to know such details

Comment: Understood and agreed. But for what it's worth, setting PYTHONIOENCODING is the only resolution that I can find unfortunately.